# Dapper stored procedure has too many arguments specified when passing IEnumerable to it

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

I'm calling my procedure by this method:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Algorithm>> GetAlgorithmsByNameAsync(IEnumerable<string> names)
{
    var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
    parameters.Add("@names", names);

    var connection = _connection.GetOpenConnection();   
    return await connection.QueryAsync<Algorithm>("GetAlgorithmsByName", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}
```

My Procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[StringList] AS TABLE(
    [Item] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL
);

--PROCEDURE HERE--

CREATE PROCEDURE GetAlgorithmsByName

@names StringList READONLY -- my own type

AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ALgorithmId, Name From Algorithms WHERE Name IN (SELECT Item FROM @names)
END
```

From the code above, I get an error:

> "Procedure or function GetAlgorithmsByName has too many arguments specified."

What am I doing wrong? How do I pass `IEnumerable<string>` to a stored procedure using dapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your stored procedure is expecting `[Item] [NVARCHAR](MAX)`, it means one item Whereas you are passing `IEnumerable<string> names`. So that's the reason why you are getting the error.

There are numerous way to pass the list of string to sp

1. XML
2. Using [table-valued parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-table-valued-parameters?view=sql-server-ver15) like `CREATE TYPE NameList AS TABLE ( Name Varchar(100) );`
3. Using `names = "Name1, Name2, .. , Namen";` then sql you can use [T-SQL split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string) to get the name list

---

**Updated**
You are passing param incorrectly, Let's fix it by this way

```
     using (var table = new DataTable()) 
     {
      table.Columns.Add("Item", typeof(string));

      for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
        table.Rows.Add(i.ToString());

      var pList = new SqlParameter("@names", SqlDbType.Structured);
      pList.TypeName = "dbo.StringList";
      pList.Value = table;

      parameters.Add(pList);
   }
```

Comment: Your second option is what OP has in the question

Comment: Oops, sorry my bad. Let me updated my answer. Thanks sir.

Comment: I've just updated my answer, please take a look @Marc Gravell♦  However, In my opinion, the params is quite simple, OP no need to create `table-valued parameters `, should use option 3 instead.

Comment: The code at the end seems to ignore the fact that OP is using dapper, not raw ADO.NET; the data-table bit looks fine, but there's an extension method - something like AsTableValuedParameter that is used with Dapper

Comment: Thanks for your advices! I will check everything soon when i will be back to my project :)

Comment: @Anonymous i like the solution with spliting string (3. paragraph) because its looks simplest. Can you tell me, how to deal with this function in procedure? Do i need to `DECLARE @value` that attach to that value strings, something like `DECLARE @names = SELECT * FROM dbo.split('1,2,3')` and then i will query from `@names` like from table? What type `@names` should be?

Comment: type `@names` should be `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. As you can see, it returns `table` instead of `string`. So you can join to get value accordingly

Answer (score 3):

Table valued parameters aren't trivial to use; one way is via the extension method that Dapper adds on `DataTable` (something like `AsTableValuedParameter`), but: it doesn't work as simply as `IEnumerable<T>` - at least, not today. You also probably don't need `DynamicParameters` here.

If what you want is just a set of strings, then one very pragmatic option is to look at the inbuilt `string_split` API in SQL Server, if you can define a separator token that is never used in the data. Then you can just pass a single delimited string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IEnumerable (dynamic) rather than IEnumerable (string).

Check this link and try [How to Implement IEnumerable (dynamic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39839231/stored-procedures-ef-and-net-core/39839709#39839709)